# file not found after doing sudo chown apache:apache -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite

Tags: apache, centos7, sudo, chown

I had python execution file problem and I tried a proposed solution
which is
sudo chown apache:apache -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite

and now my website is not accessible
I have "File Not Found"
Don't know what to do now.

I am on apache centos.

Thank you for help

```html
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys


url=sys.argv[1]

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("headless")
option.add_argument("--whitelisted-ips=''");
option.add_argument("disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: You shouldn't have ran `chown`. Instead, you should've ran `chmod`, because that was probably the problem with the python file. Let me do some research and come back for this issue. Was it working before you ran `chown`? Show me your virtualhosts, and your httpd.conf.

Comment: Thank you - I have undo whith doing chown myuser:mygroup -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite and my website was up again but I have still my problem with python. To be precise, it is not a python problem but a selenium/chromedriver. I can execute my python script which uses selenium in root ssh. But when calling the same python script in an exec() php command, the script doesn't work. The chromedriver doesn't seem to start and I can't see any error in the log file. I have found other similar subject with same problem but not any solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Post the first few lines of the python script (Including the content-type and stuff) on your question please.